# Calculate the payment for the interest rate effective per period

Tags: r

I have one fibo.seq function and try to write a program with three arguments: one called n (with no default value), one called i (with no default value), and one called arrears (with default value set to TRUE). assume that n≥3.

Present Value of a stream of n payments F1,F2,…,Fn , where the kth payment Fk corresponds to the kth number in the Fibonacci sequence (1≤k≤n), and where payments happen at regular time intervals.

The interest rate effective per period is equal to argument i. Example: if i=0.05, the rate of interest effective per period is 5%.

If arguments arrears=TRUE, then the first payment happens at the end of the first period. Otherwise, the first payment happens immediately.

I can call a function (e.g. fibo.seq) for fibonacci sequence

Clarification (added on 03/10/2020): fibo.PV must return the total Present Value of payments (i.e. a single number).

Can we use the annuity for it?

```
fibo.PV <- function(n, i, arrears=TRUE) {
  if (arrears) {
    PV <- numeric(n)
    PV <- annuity(i=0.05, n=5, type="immediately")
  } else {
    PV <- annuity(i=0.06/12, n=5*12)
  }
  return(PV)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `"immediate"` instead of `"immediately"`?

Comment: fibo.PV <- function(n, i, arrears=TRUE) {
  if (arrears) {
    PV <- numeric(n)
    PV <- annuity(i=0.05, n=5, type="immediate")
  } else {
    PV <- annuity(i=0.06/12, n=5*12)
  }
  return(PV)
}

Answer (score 0):

This code should be enough for you to create the function

```
library(tidyverse)

i <- .05

# Data frame with cash flows
df <- tibble(
  fibo = fibo.seq(length) ) %>% 
  mutate(index = row_number(),
         flow = fibo/(1+i)^(index))

# calculate PV
df %>% 
  summarise(pv = sum(flow, na.rm = TRUE))
```